# Don't understan how to implement simple_form create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

*Note: I'm using Rails 3.2*

I'm trying to implement a simple_form by following this sample code: https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb. I have a Summary model instead of an Article model.

I understand most of what's going on, except for the two private methods. I tried basically copying the code except for the two private methods, and what it does is it creates a new Summary, but the attributes are all nil.

1) How are attributes saved? What's the difference between `.new` and `.save`?

2) What is available in the create action? When you reach the create action, you've just filled out a form, so something must be available, but I don't know what it is, or how it becomes available.

3) What's going on with the `before_action` and the two private methods?

Summaries Controller

```
class SummariesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :set_summary, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @summaries = Summary.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @summary = Summary.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
        @summary = Summary.new(params[:summary])

        if @summary.save
            redirect_to @summary, notice: 'Summary created.'
        else
            render :new
        end
    end


    def update
        if @summary.update(params[:summary])
            redirect_to @summary, notice: 'Summary updated.'
        else
            render :edit
        end 
    end

    def destroy
        @summary.destroy
        redirect_to summaries_url, notice: 'Summary destroyed'
    end

    private
        # sets @summary to make available for show, edit, update 
        # and destroy actions so code isn't repetitive
        def set_summary
          @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
        # def summary_params
        #  params[:summary].permit!
        #end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) `new` is a Ruby method for initializing a new instance of an object. So when you call `Article.new`, you get a new instance of the `Article` class.

[`save`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) is a Rails method for saving a record to the database. If your object instance is instantiated with `new`, it calls `create` under the hood. If you loaded the object through a finder (`find`, `all`, `where`, etc.), then it will call `update` under the hood instead of `create`.

2) A hash named `params` is available in all actions (and in the view). In the case of the `create` action, `params[:article]`, which is the data posted by the form. At the top of `create`, try calling `raise params[:article].to_yaml` to see what's going on in there.

Heck, even try `raise params.to_yaml` to see what's in there.

3) The call to `before_action` runs the `set_article` private method before the `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy` actions. Without that, you'd need to manually call `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` in every single one of those actions. So this eliminates quite a bit of repetition!

You'll notice that the first line of the `create` action calls the `article_params` method. This is a common way of implementing what are called strong parameters in Rails. Strong parameters are new in Rails 4 but can be added to earlier versions of Rails via the [`strong_parameters` gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm slightly confused by `params[:article]`. Is it a 2d array? Like `params[:article][:id]`?

Comment: Also, the update action isn't working. It's giving me this error: `private method `update' called for #<Summary:0x007f83e3fc9d60>`. Would you mind explaining to me what's wrong and how to fix it? I added my Summaries Controller to the question.

Comment: `params[:article]` is a hash of everything submitted by the form. Hashes are kind of like associative arrays in other languages. So it may contain keys like `params[:article][:id]`, `params[:article][:title]`, and `params[:article][:content]`, for example.

Comment: Change `@summary.update(params[:summary])` to `@summary.update_attributes(params[:summary])`. `update_attributes` was renamed to `update` in Rails 4, but you'll need to call `update_attributes` in earlier versions of Rails like 3.2.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep going. You'll find Ruby on Rails to be a very enjoyable development environment once you learn the ropes!